# Play Iteratees: error for simple file iteration

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, loops

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around the idea of `Enumerators` and `Iteratees`. I decided to start off by looking at Play 2.0's iteratee library, which I've added to my test project with the following lines in my *build.sbt* file. (I am using Scala 2.10) ([docs here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.package))

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at 
  "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "play" %% "play-iteratees" % "2.1.1"
```

My goal is to create an Enumerator over the bytes of a file, and eventually attach some parsing logic to it, but when I try what appears to be a simple thing, I get an exception.
My code looks like this:

```
val instr = getClass.getResourceAsStream(...)
val streamBytes = for {
  chunk <- Enumerator fromStream instr
  byte <- Enumerator enumerate chunk
} yield byte

val printer = Iteratee.foreach[Byte](println)

streamBytes.apply(printer)
```

What happens is that (what I assume is) all of the bytes in the file get printed, then I get an `IllegalStateException` saying that the "Promise already completed".

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Promise already completed.
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:58)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.failure(Promise.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.failure(Promise.scala:58)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.liftedTree3$1(Future.scala:283)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:277)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:274)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Since the stack trace doesn't point to anywhere in my code, and this is unfamiliar territory, I have no idea what's going wrong. Can anyone offer some insight or a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you.  I was getting exceptions with your code too, but when I unwound your for-comp, things worked.  I'm not 100% sure why because I thought the for-comp desugared to this code anyway, but I must be missing something:

```
val bytes = Enumerator fromStream instr flatMap (Enumerator enumerate _)    
val printer = Iteratee.foreach[Byte](b => println(b))    
bytes |>> printer
```

Comment: This is weird... I tried the same thing again (at work this time), but instead of an Exception, it just hangs forever once the printing is done. Even with the code you gave, it hangs. I'm going to have to try this again later on (after work), and get back to you.

Comment: I got some down time and found out that my most recent attempt is hanging because there is an internal `ExecutionContext` that is being used instead of the one I actually wanted, and it's creating non-daemon threads. This seems like a bug in Play, no?

Comment: Agreed.  The `enumerate` requires an implicit `ExecutionContext`.  When I give it one and then shutdown that context when the printing is done, my server still stays up and that's not what I was expecting.  Certainly warrants further investigation.  If you pull it up in jconsole, you can see a thread pool called iteratee-execution-context.

Comment: Looks like it's in the works: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/issues/807 I'll just mark this answer as accepted since it led to some helpful info.